# How to display ripple animation on google map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to set ripple animation on `google map` using specific Lat-Lng, please see [this](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background) which exactly describes what I wants, I referred above link but unable to set animation on `google map`.

What I tried so far is-

My xml code:

```
<com.test.custom.RippleBackground
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rippleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:rb_color="#0099CC"
        app:rb_duration="5000"        
        app:rb_radius="32dp"
        app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
        app:rb_scale="6" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMapProfile"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_active" />
    </com.test.custom.RippleBackground>
```

My Java code to place ripple on google map:

```
 LatLng currentAddressLatLong;              
                        currentAddressLatLong = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());

                    RippleBackground rippleLayout=(RippleBackground)findViewById(R.id.rippleLayout);
                    rippleLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ImageView imgMapProfile=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMapProfile);

                    Bitmap markerUserBitmap = Comman.createDrawableFromView(NearByActivity.this, rippleLayout);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentAddressLatLong).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerUserBitmap)));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentAddressLatLong));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

                    rippleLayout.startRippleAnimation();

     // Convert a view to bitmap function
            public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) 
            {
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
                view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
                view.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                view.draw(canvas);

                return bitmap;
            }
```

But the bitmap is not getting animate. please help. thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the layout should overlay on the Google map, and I found that this library is using extends `RelativeLayout`, It should at least `FrameLayout` to do the overlay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For everyone who wants to create ripple background in google map like this [image]

1. Create 3 GroundOverlay with same circle. Put image in drawable folder
2. Create Value Animator
3. Send 3 GroundOverlay in ValueAnimator periodically
   Below code:
   Inside onCreateView

> ```
>  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>                    @Override public void run() {final GroundOverlay groundOverlay11=googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new
>         GroundOverlayOptions()
>                            .position(latLng, 2000)
>                            .transparency(0.5f)
>                            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.krug)));
>                     OverLay(groundOverlay11);
>                    }
>                   }, 0);
> ```

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        final GroundOverlay groundOverlay1=googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .position(latLng, 2000)
                .transparency(0.5f)
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.krug)));
        OverLay(groundOverlay1);
       }
      }, 4000);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        final GroundOverlay groundOverlay2=googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .position(latLng, 2000)
                .transparency(0.5f)
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.krug)));
        OverLay(groundOverlay2);
       }
      }, 8000);
```

And Overlay class:

```
public void OverLay(final GroundOverlay groundOverlay){
  vAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 2000);
  int r=99999;
  vAnimator.setRepeatCount(r);
  //vAnimator.setIntValues(0, 500);
  vAnimator.setDuration(12000);
  vAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
  vAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
  vAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
    float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
    Integer i = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    groundOverlay.setDimensions(i);
   }
  });
  vAnimator.start();
 }
```

Comment: Is there way to have the pulse animation be independent of the zoom level of the map? If I zoom in the map the animation zooms as well

Comment: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.
Getting error.
pls attached **R.drawable.krug** file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to yeldos I just modfiy his code for adding a fade out effect at the end of the animation.

Add this line inside the overlay function

```
groundOverlay.setTransparency(animatedFraction);
```

Just below

```
groundOverlay.setDimensions(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an android library to show ripple effects on google maps. Using this library, just 2 line of code is needed to show ripple effect on google maps as per your question.
Please visit this link for the library to show ripple: https://github.com/aarsy/GoogleMapsRippleEffect

Comment: I have tried this library. For many devices it does not work and gives an "Out of memory exception". It seems to be an ongoing issue with the library.

Answer (score 0):

create file in animfolder 
sclae_fade.xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    />
```

create circle_pulse.xml file in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#5532a9f3"/>
            <size
                android:width="120dp"
                android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
                android:width="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#32a9f3"/>
            <size
                android:width="90dp"
                android:height="90dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

now set animation

```
Animation logoMoveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_fade);
image_view.startAnimation(logoMoveAnimation);
```